# How should I name the tag of "Kono Subarashii Sekai ni Shukufuku wo! -Kono Yokubukai Game ni Shinpan o!"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I wanted to ask a question about "Kono Subarashii Sekai ni Shukufuku wo! -Kono Yokubukai Game ni Shinpan o!" (on English: "KonoSuba: God's Blessing on this Wonderful World! Judgment on this Greedy Game!"), but the official names on both Japanese and English are too long.

Considering that [konosuba-judgment-on-this-greedy-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba-judgment-on-this-greedy-game) is over the limit of 35 characters (37): How should I name the tag?

Please note that there are multiple Konosuba games, so using [konosuba](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba) or [konosuba-gods-blessing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba-gods-blessing) is not an option.

[Here is the question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/361860/199843) that I asked, with the [ps4](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ps4) tag for now.

Comment: A 73 character name, of which the first 38 characters are not unique in the series? It's as if they didn't want people to ever talk about it. Reminds me of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUJb1BD63ME

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on a discussion with Lemon and Wrigglenite below, the top level tag has been made [konosuba-judgement-greedy-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba-judgement-greedy-game).

I have made a bunch of synonyms that should reflect the full game name as best as possible too to aid in searching:

- [konosuba-wonderful-world-judgment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba-wonderful-world-judgment)
- [konosuba-gods-blessing-judgement](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba-gods-blessing-judgement)
- [judgment-on-this-greedy-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/judgment-on-this-greedy-game)
- [konosuba-greedy-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/konosuba-greedy-game)

Comment: "KonoSuba: God's Blessing on this Wonderful World!" is the series' name, so this might be ambiguous.

Comment: @Wrigglenite ah. How about [konosuba-gods-blessing-judgement]?

Comment: @Wrigglenite Correct, that is the [name of the Anime](http://www.crunchyroll.com/konosuba-gods-blessing-on-this-wonderful-world).

Comment: @Robotnik [konosuba-judgement-greedy-game] is better than [konosuba-gods-blessing-judgement] because the "gods-blessing" might be ambiguous

Comment: Maybe [konosuba-greedy-game]? These titles are way too long.

Comment: does the tag need the word 'konosuba' in the main tag? What about [judgment-on-this-greedy-game] with various synonyms that have 'konosuba' in them?

Comment: @Robotnik if you ask me, yes. The game is usually referred as "the Konosuba game on PS4".

Comment: @Lemon alright in that case let's go with [konosuba-judgement-greedy-game], I think that's the closest we're gonna get :)

Comment: Yep, that is the best one that I can see under or equal to 35 characters in length. Also, I would recommend [judgment-on-this-greedy-game] as a synonym in case that someone searches the full game name.